# undoing shared merge feature branch from remote

Tags: git, github, gitlab

- I have a **develop branch** and a **features branch** called
  init-work .
- **I push my changes in the gitlab**
- Before i do a pull request I accidentally merge my init-work into
  develop.
- So now I need to unmerge my init-work from develop.

[image]
How do I go about this?

Here's what I'm thinking:
i think to do *git push -f feature/init-work* no ?

Comment: Can you add the text in the screenshot as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a multiuser project, it's better to revert it, then rebase the feature branch so that git *thinks* that it is not merged at all.

```
git checkout develop
git revert HEAD # given that it is the last commit in the branch
git push origin develop # push it into the remote
git checkout feature/init-work
git commit --amend --no-edit # create a brand new revision separate from the one that was merged/reverted in develop
# now it can be rebased on top of develop
git rebase develop
```

Comment: that what i have when i log : the origin/feature/init-work is behind 1 commit to the    feature/init-work                                                                                                                      `$ git log --oneline --all --graph 
* 69b8654 (feature/init-work) use a lazy loading concept
* 44e2dbc (HEAD -> develop, origin/feature/init-work, origin/develop, origin/HEAD) use a lazy loading concept
* a0f562c (tag: v1.0) add karma`

Comment: the feature/init-work still in the remote and it still merged with the develop

Comment: Sure... and, as I said, _assuming_ it's a multiuser project, you **should not** remove it (like a `git reset --hard` and force-push) because it will be a pain if others users have already pulled it.

Comment: Oh.... and if you mean that the remote branch is still pointing to the original merged commit, that will change when you (force)push the branch into the remote after having rebased it.